# export setup from an old plone 2.1.4

Tags: plone

I have to migrate an old plone 2.1.4 site to 4.1. I wanted to export workflows, portal_languages, etc trough portal_setup and then adjust them by hand in order to create proper packages, but it seems plone 2.1.4 doesn't have one.

Is there any known-good-way to get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a product that can dump the workflow and rebuild it, works for 2.1:

http://plone.org/products/dcworkflowdump

Project Description

Dumps DCWorkflow specifications into a python script.

Then, you can import in a plone3 site and export it or use it in some migration step. Should work.

Comment: Back on the project :)It requires too much work for my use case but thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. uninstall all third party add-ons
2. copy the data.fs to a plone3 environment
3. use upgrade step plone2.1->plone3
4. export everything you need

Comment: unfortunately there's too many crap into my data.fs. it does not work on plone 3.1.7 neither on 2.5. I think the fastest solution is copy workflow & co by hand :(